# Got Noisy Log From Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

Running the app in Android Q Emulator, there is no error in the code bu i got this log from glide. is this a bug? if it is, can i hide this log? thanks

> Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file (ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.

Comment: Same story, did u finally find a reason?

Answer (score 0):

That's likely telling you that something attempted to load an image that is not supported. Glide allows you to define which log level you want it to use. You can see the docs for this [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#log-level).